# WPF Focus visible window when main window minimized

Tags: wpf, focus

I have a child window which is always visible, think of a tasktray notification window. My issue is when the main window is minimized I am unable to click on this window.

The child window is still aware of when the mouse enters it so I was hoping to write some code to make it focusable.

Any thoughts on what I would need to set, without restoring the main window i.e. not bringing it to the foreground and keeping it minimized

Best regards

Emlyn

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can teach your App class (or some Util) to handle your childForm instance.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private MyFormClass forminstance = null;

    internal static void ShowMyForm()
    {
        if (forminstance == null)
            forminstance = new MyFormClass();

        if (!forminstance.IsVisible)
            forminstance.Show();
    }

    internal static void HideMyForm()
    {
        if (forminstance != null && forminstance.IsVisible)
            forminstance.Hide();
    }

}
```

And call the methods from your Main window. If it is the place where you control the child.

```
App.ShowMyForm();
```

(i didn't test this code).